# Product page needs to be refresh after customer login in new tab of same browser in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, addtocart, shopping-cart, mini-cart

I am stuck in one problem with Magento.

When I click Addtocart button on product page of Magento, Product successfully adds in Cart and than I open the Customer Login Page in New Tab of same browser and than I Login successfully in that New Tab, But now the problem is when I go back the Product Page Tab and click AddtoCart button than product is not adding into Cart until I refresh the product page.

How I can add product in cart without refreshing the page after Login the customer account in another Tab of same browser?

Will appreciate any help please.

Thanks

Comment: any one please help. any idea will be highly appreciated please

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem the product page must be reloaded to take the new cookies and session created in the customer loggin page

For exemple if you loggin in stackexchange in a new tab but not in this tab you will see that you are still not logged in this tab.

Comment: thanks for the reply but many of the other ecommerce sites and even magento platform sites are not needed to be refreshed and successfully adds the product in Cart once after login in another Tab of same browser.

Comment: if you use ajax to add product might be happened

Comment: But i have an examples of Magento Site which is using Ajax for adding product in Cart and That is also adding the product in cart after login in another Tab in same browser.

Comment: can you share a link to see what's happend

Comment: am i allowed to share the url here?

Comment: yes i think so use "[ link ]( exmple.com )" [link](http://example.com)

Comment: ok. but i think its not good to post the url of someones website publicly.